# Dynamic Table Creation In html Using CGI

Tags: html, dynamic, html-table, cgi

I'm trying to print some data in tables by using the below code (not entire code) but it's giving error.
If I remove the table then I'm able to print the output. Can anybody help me with this?

```
print "<table border="1">\n";
while(my $ref = $sth->fetchrow_hashref()) {
print "<tr>\n";
print "<td>\n ";
print "$ref->{'name'} owns $ref->{'telno'}\n";
print "</td>\n";
print "</tr>\n";
}
print "</table>\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
print "<table border="1">\n";
```

Don't you need to escape those inner double quotes?